# HTML, Javascript: Display only few digits on form view, but all digits on editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It seems a common problem, but I found no solution on SO.

Now I have

```js
var my_setter = function(key, value) {
  $('#' + key).val(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Some float number
<input id="key1" class="number2digit" type="text">
</label>
```

Supposing I have `value = 3.14159265359`. I want:

- Normally show only 2 digit (`3.14`), right aligned
- On mouse over the "title": `3.14159265359`
- On editing: the precise value: `3.14159265359` left aligned.

Is there a short way to do it in CSS or jQuery or in some other well know JS libraries, without requiring me to implement it with a lot of event listeners?

Comment: I would simply use the precise value on title-attribute and input-elements value-attribute then the rounded-value in another "read only"-element. Then just show/hide "read only"-element and the input-element with javascript when the user clicks "edit".

Comment: i think you need `focus`, `blur` and `mouseenter` events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var defaultText = '';
  $('#key1').focus(function() {
    $(this).val(defaultText);
  });
  $('#key1').blur(function() {
    defaultText = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(parseFloat(defaultText).toFixed(2));
  });
  $('label[for=key1]').mouseenter(function() {
    console.log(defaultText);
  });
});
```

```css
#key1 {
  text-align: right;
}

#key1:focus {
   text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="key1">Some float number</label>
<input id="key1" class="number2digit" type="text">
```

***Note:*** See my changes on your label.

```
<label for="key1">Some float number</label>
<input id="key1" class="number2digit" type="text">
```

vs yours:

```
<label>Some float number
<input id="key1" class="number2digit" type="text">
</label>
```

You can either, depending on your requirement.

> 1. If you only want to show value on the label's mouseover, use my version.
> 2. If you want to show value on label or the input's mouseover, continue using your version, but you will need to change something in the javascript event.

Change the selector `$('label[for=key1]')` to `$('#key1').closest('label')`.

And for the alignment of the value, you can use css `focus`:

```
#key1 {
  text-align: right;
}

#key1:focus {
   text-align: left;
}
```

I hope this helps.

***EDIT:*** Even better, you can use this instead. You will only need two events - `focus` and `blur` since you only want something like a tooltip, `title` attr for label, in which case you can use either label format. Of course you might be doing something other than displaying title, then you can use the previous snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  var defaultText = '';
  $('#key1').focus(function() {
    $(this).val(defaultText);
  });
  $('#key1').blur(function() {
    defaultText = $(this).val();
    var fVal = parseFloat(defaultText)
    if (fVal) {
      $(this).val(fVal.toFixed(2));
      $('#key1').closest('label').attr('title', defaultText);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#key1 {
  text-align: right;
}

#key1:focus {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Some float number
    <input id="key1" class="number2digit" type="text">
</label>
```

Comment: Just an idea for the mouseover part, perhaps the mouseover event could simply trigger a focus event.

Comment: depends on OP though. but i think what he wants is the updated snippet so mouseover is not needed.